# Create two columns, first is one word, the other is all text left over from that line using awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

**How it looks with sed and grep**
This is the output of /etc/sudoers file:

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%galaxy ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

As you can see, it is messy (it is filtered with grep to exclude comments, and with sed to remove all empty lines). It is kinda complicated to explain but here is the output I want to achieve.

**What I want to achieve:**

```
Defaults   env_reset 
Defaults   mail_badpass
Defaults   secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin
root       ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%admin     ALL=(ALL) ALL
%galaxy    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo      ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I want to space separate this into TWO columns.

1. First column is one word
2. Second column contains the remaining text.

**How it looks so far:**
I tried with this awk command, but cannot make it to include all other $X and treat them as second column.

```
grep -v -E "^#" /etc/sudoers 2>/dev/null | sed -e '/^$/d' | awk -F" " '{printf "%-10s %-10s\n",$1,$2}'

Defaults   env_reset 
Defaults   mail_badpass
Defaults   secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin
root       ALL=(ALL:ALL)
%admin     ALL=(ALL) 
%galaxy    ALL=(ALL) 
%sudo      ALL=(ALL:ALL)
```

This command would give me wanted results, but obviously, awk cannot see more than $2, therefore following words are not shown.

Comment: Welcome to SO and special thanks for showing your efforts in form of code. Could you please also do mention expected output in your question and let us know then for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: The first block of code in my answer shows what I want to achieve. If you run the last command, it will do just that, but it misses all remaining characters (in this case my command wont work because the 4 "ALL" words are missed by awk (because space separation with -F). I want to make sure the second column contains all following characters, and in sudoers there will be many. Thank you.

Comment: Why I was asking your end output, because if we see that then we could do it in a single awk command itself then, so request you to be clear in sample exact output which will help us more to understand problem clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `substr`. You have `$1` already; `substr($0,length($1)+1)` returns everything after it.

You can also lose the [useless `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) and `sed`.

```sh
awk '!/^#/ && $0 {
    rest = substr($0, length($1)+1);
    sub(/^[ \t]*/, "", rest);
    printf "%-10s %-10s\n",$1, rest }' /etc/sudoers
```